# JSON array without key - Logic Apps Azure

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

My JSON array is as follows.

```
[{"20656":"20656","20648":"20648","20666":"20666","20657":"20657","20658":"20658","20659":"20659","20660":"20660","20665":"20665","20672":"20672","20667":"20667","24517":"24517","20677":"20677","20662":"20662","24605":"24605","20675":"20675","20663":"20663","20649":"20649","20664":"20664","20668":"20668","20669":"20669","20670":"20670","20671":"20671","20673":"20673","20674":"20674","20676":"20676"}]
```

How do I use each individual value and use it as a variable for my next query.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you contact the provider and ask them to send you JSON that is more in the spirit of JSON?  Even just an Array of values would be better.  The format they chose is (variable element names) adding unnecessary complication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your variable looks like this

[image]

Add **Select Action**

[image]

Which has **From** property set to

```
split(replace(replace(replace(variables('MyJsonArray'),'[{',''),'}]',''),'"',''),',')
```

And **Map** to pair **MyID** with expression

```
substring(item(),0,lastIndexOf(item(),':'))
```

Now you can simply iternate over all IDs with simple **Foreach** and refer to each ID by using expression

```
item()['MyID']
```

[image]

Comment: perfect. Works!

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Parse JSON" action to parse your json data.

First, I create a "Initialize variable" action to store the json data(shown as below screenshot)

[image]

Then create "Parse JSON" action to parse the json object above.

[image]

If you don't know how to create the schema, you can click "Use sample payload to generate schema" and input your json data into it. It will generate the schema for you automatically. You can also refer to this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action

After that, we can use each individual value as variable in our logic app.(I created "Initialize variable 2" in the screenshot below as an example).

[image]

Comment: Sorry, the "Type" in the first screenshot should be "Array". I have updated my answer.

Comment: I tried that but the values change every month. So, parse JSON gets confused.